# Problem getting language pragma OVERLAPPING to work

Tags: haskell, ghc

I cannot get the following instances to work :

```
newtype ParseState a = ParseState {
  state :: a
} deriving (Show)

newtype Parse m a b = Parse { -- In monad m, parsing from state a to b
  runParse :: ParseState a -> m (b,ParseState a)
}

instance Monad m => Monad (Parse m a) where
  parser >>= f = Parse $ \s -> do
    (result,s') <- runParse parser s
    runParse (f result) s'

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Monad m, Show a) => Monad (Parse m a) where
  (>>=) = -- same definition as above
  fail err = Parse $ \s ->
    fail $ "Parsing error while at" ++ (show s) ++ " : " ++ err
```

GHC gives me the error "Duplicate instance declarations". [Section 7.6.3.4 of GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) seems to allow for such constructs, doesn't it ?

If not, how can I get around it ?

Comment: This is getting to be an FAQ. GHC doesn't look at instance constraints when resolving overlap. Only the part to the right of the double arrow is considered. Since those are the same for your instances, they'll be rejected.

Comment: Also: You've linked to the manual for GHC 7.6.3, which is now quite old. Did you do that on purpose?

Comment: No, I thought it was a chapter... I am going to read the one for the version I have.

Comment: It also seems peculiar that a `Monad` instance would have any use for a `Show` constraint. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I would like fail to be able to "print" the state I am at. I will update my post to show this.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't always get what you want. You can overlap for *specific* types, but not for classes. And I think you should think twice and thrice before overlapping, and then think again. It can come back to bite you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's still a pickle.

Comment: Side note: these days, it's probably better to use `MonadFail` for `fail` rather than `Monad`. That means enabling `-XMonadFailDesugaring` and defining a `MonadFail` instance. If I were you, I'd either 1. Give the `MonadFail (Parse m a)` a `Show a` constraint, and offer a custom failure function that *doesn't* show the state, or 2. Leave the instance unconstrained and offer a custom failure function that shows the state. Option (2) seems much cleaner. It would be my choice, especially because knowing only the parser state doesn't really seem likely to be very helpful when (cont)

Comment: (cont) there's a pattern match failure and you can't see what failed to match.